# Calling methods from outside a class in Python - Tkinter events

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to call a method in another class and make changes to the parent class when the button is clicked in Python. To explain; With Tkinter visual programming, I click the button to change the main window and I can not change the properties in the main window with another class method.

I get the error message below.

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/_ *init* _.py", line 1553, in _
>   *call* _
>
> return self.func(*args) TypeError: buton_goster() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'

---

```
class Butonol(object): #Button class


    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def buton_goster(self, event ): # Properties kisminda ozellik gosterir

        Test.countshow = Test.countshow + 1;
        if(Test.countshow >1):
            Test.props0.pack_forget()
            Test.props.pack_forget()
            ...
```

And here is the Test Class

```
class Test(Frame):

    countshow = 0

    ...
    def new_Button(self):
        self.nesne = Butonol()
        self.but= Button(self.mainFrame,text = self.nesne.text)
        self.but.bind('<Button-1>',Butonol.buton_goster)
        self.but.bind('B1-Motion>',self.label_tasi)
        self.but.pack(side = LEFT,anchor = N)
        Butonol.butonsay = Butonol.butonsay + 1
        Butonol.butonliste.append(self.but)
```

Comment: Change `bind('<Button-1>', Butonol.buton_goster)` to `bind('<Button-1>', self.but.buton_goster)`.

Comment: The "buton_ol" method is in the Butonol class, so when I do that I want the "buton_goster" method in the Test class. I want to call the buton_goster method from the Butonol class.

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct, 
When you do you bind, you do not pass on the event, you simply add the function pointer.

If the buton_goster does not need "event" you should remove it or you should provide event as input when calling the function.

Comment: In the following parts of the method, assignments are made as event.widget . I get an error when I remove the event parameter